# Eclipse Android: Didn't find class

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, compiler-errors

Im doing the following tutorial on creating an Android App using Google App Engine: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

I am using Eclipse in Windows 7. I got to the part where you run the application to display the newly uploaded information from "places.csv". The problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151): Process: com.apps.mobileassistant, PID: 1151
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.apps.mobileassistant/com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apps.mobileassistant-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.apps.mobileassistant-2, /system/lib]]
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apps.mobileassistant-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.apps.mobileassistant-2, /system/lib]]
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-15 17:00:31.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
```

MobileAssistant App Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.apps.mobileassistant">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <permission android:name="com.apps.mobileassistant.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

   <uses-permission android:name="com.apps.mobileassistant.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
   <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.apps.mobileassistant"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.apps.mobileassistant"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Also when in debug mode I get a "Source Not Found" error in Thread[<1> main].

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Just as it is exactly what your current message error is saying to you:

```
ComponentInfo{com.apps.mobileassistant/com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.apps.mobileassistant.MainActivity" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apps.mobileassistant-2.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.apps.mobileassistant-2
```

You either have made some mistake on setting up your project and required library, or simply has some class missing, or has not informed in your code the respective class through import and the class name.